# Getting custom hyphenation patterns to work in xelatex

Tags: xetex, hyphenation

I have a file `mylanguage.tex` that contains hyphenation patterns for `mylanguage`:

```
\newlanguage\mylanguage
\begingroup
\language\mylanguage
\patterns{
1b
}
\endgroup
```

And a test file `foo.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\language=\mylanguage
\usepackage{testhyphens}

\begin{document}
\begin{checkhyphens}{}
foobar
\end{checkhyphens}
\end{document}
```

I expect the word `foobar` in `foo.tex` to be tokenized as `foo-bar`.

To compile everything, I do this:

```
xelatex -jobname=mylanguage -ini "&xelatex mylanguage\dump"
xelatex -fmt mylanguage foo
```

However, the first command outputs this error message:

```
Too late for \patterns.
```

The corresponding help message says:

```
All patterns must be given before typesetting begins.
```

I tried to ignore the error message and proceed, and indeed manage to output a PDF at the end, but my custom hyphenation pattern are ignored and I get `foobar` without hyphens in the output.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thank you very much for this question. I used the solution here and it worked. However when I use babel (because titles for my language is already exists in babel) it does not work. Do you have any idea with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can input the `xelatex.ini` source rather than recycling the format.

Change your `mylanguage.tex` to

```
\let\DUMP\dump
\let\dump\relax
\input xelatex.ini
\newlanguage\mylanguage
\begingroup
\language\mylanguage
\patterns{
1b
}
\endgroup
\let\dump\DUMP
\let\DUMP\undefined
\dump
```

then a commandline of

```
xelatex -etex -ini  mylanguage
```

shows your new language as  85:

```
...
Hyphenation trie of length 437140 has 9487 ops out of 35111
  1 for language 85
  143 for language 84

...
```