# Why does hyphenation orphan combining accents?

Tags: babel, unicode, hyphenation, polyglossia, greek

While testing a package I was writing to map Greek [beta code](http://stephanus.tlg.uci.edu/history.php) to Unicode, I discovered a bug in both Babel and Polyglossia, running under either XeTeX or LuaTeX.  The packages will happily insert a hyphenation point between a base character and its combining accents, orphaning the accents in the margin of the next line.
These MWEs reproduce the bug with canonically-equivalent characters in precomposed and decomposed form.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[greek.ancient]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\babelfont{rm}[Ligatures={Common,Discretionary}]{Libertinus Serif}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\parbox{0pt}{
Hyphenate: % The first word in a paragraph is unhyphenated.
^^^^1faf^^^^03a9^^^^0314^^^^0342^^^^0345
}
\end{document}
```

[image: Libertinus Serif sample]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}[Ligatures={Common, Discretionary}, Script=Greek]
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\parbox{0pt}{
Hyphenate: % The first word in a paragraph is unhyphenated.
^^^^1faf^^^^03a9^^^^0314^^^^0342^^^^0345
}
\end{document}
```

[image: Libertinus Serif sample]

The bug does not go away if I instead load `\babelprovide[import=el-poluton]{greek}`.

A workaround is to convert all characters to precomposed NFC form, but this violates the requirement of [the Unicode standard](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Canon_Compat_Equivalence) that “Canonical equivalence is a fundamental equivalency between characters or sequences of characters which represent the same abstract character, and which when correctly displayed should always have the same visual appearance and behavior.”  (This is now incorporated into the main document itself, in sections 3.6, 3.11 and elsewhere.)

Comment: There was a similar bug for Russian [back in 2017](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339242/avoid-hyphenation-before-combining-accents). (Not the same as this one.)

Comment: Experiment shows, if I am on the right rack,  that a compiled custom hyphenation `.fmt` file, built along the lines of (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498865/getting-custom-hyphenation-patterns-to-work-in-xelatex) and full of `8^^^^0314`-type instructions, works. I take it that the preferred solution should be at `babel`/`polyglossia` level or earlier, in which case all the combining diacritic mark hyphenation patterns can be put into a central file, and `input`ted into all the other pattern formats where the language uses such marks and hasn't a pattern already.

Comment: @Cicada It should. There are eight accents my mapping file produces (light-breathing, heavy-breathing, dieresis, acute, grave, circumflex, iota-subscript, and dot below), several others defined in Unicode but that won’t appear in normalized output (oxia and four combinations of dieresis with acute, grave, circumflex or oxia), two regional diacritics that weren’t used in Classical Greek (macron and breve), and a couple of others that TLG thinks were occasionally used (a stroke on rho, and a dot above).

Comment: @Cicada Thanks for the reminder. I went back to fix the combining dieresis accents.

Comment: @Cicada Oh, and a few more defined in beta code (overline, underline, double underline, etc.)

Comment: Dedicated custom macros will be the way to go, I'm thinking. Perhaps also boxing everything up.

Comment: ᾯ Unrelated - looking at some fonts at random, the 'pre-composed' glyph forms are actually composites (an understandable design choice) and occasionally fail. So *correctly* becomes a key word in the specification: "... when correctly displayed ...".

Comment: @Cicada I have a mapping file that will transform a subset of beta code to NFC Unicode, which is what seems to work in XeTeX.

Comment: Yes, xetex was designed with mapping files in mind, from what I can see (I like how they use regex methods). The Lualatex equivalent involves lua code looping through the token list, so do-able there, too, with some initial effort.

Comment: @Cicada Could even conceivably do it with regex search/replace in expl3!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116507/discussion-between-davislor-and-cicada).